# pip install cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl to my window 10 machine

Tags: pip

Tryng to pip install `cx_Freeze` using:

```
python -m pip install c:\Users\yosief\Downloads\cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

on Window 10 based laptop and I end up with an error

> cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: `python --version`? Is Python 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it includes the Python version and build.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why you may not be able to install `cx_Freeze` but luckily it is generally easy to correct.

You should just be able to install `cx_Freeze` with `pip install cx_Freeze`.  No need to download the wheel.

However if you want to use the wheel file. You should know have downloaded the x64 version for Python 3.6. Your Python installation must be an x64 build and the Python version 3.6.

Check the Python version and build by opening the Python interpreter.  The version will be displayed at the top as well as the build.

For example on my PC the interpreter reads:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct 3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So I know the version is 3.6.3 and is 32 bit (`MSC v.1900 32 bit`).  Take no notice of `on win32` it does not give you the right windows build in some cases.

If the build or version is different from what you have downloaded then you must re [download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) the wheel to match the Python build and version.

Then install the wheel file as you did above.

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: This is purely a guess but I think you have an x32 version of Python installed.  The error would suggest so.