# How to fix install error in cx_freeze with pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame, cx-freeze

I was trying to install `cx_Freeze` and every time an error happens. I tried to install it with `pip`, that didn't work, and I'm trying to install this by `wheel`, downloading the `cx_freeze` file from `https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/4.3.4/#files` and using `pip` to install it by:

```
pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I already have `wheel` installed in my computer.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the actual error messages you get.

Comment: cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Do you have 32-bit Windows? Or maybe 32-bit Python? Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866866/pip-install-cx-freeze-5-0-2-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64-whl-to-my-window-10-machine

Comment: I have 64 bits windows and 64 python, what could be doing this error?

Comment: Which version of Python do you have? Run `python --version`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install cx-freeze module you do not need to mention whole file directory...
you can just type:-
pip install cx-freeze

copy this command and paste it in cmd(command prompt)

if you want to install any package you have to write:-

pip install (package name)

hope the answer will be useful